# E/AndroidRuntime(31678): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only push to a query for Installations

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am new to parse ,i am able to store data to its database and also to retrieve some information like object-id from database  but when I try to send push notification i usually get the above mentioned error.Query which i am using to send push notification with object-id corresponding to the given Friend-id.

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private RadioButton genderFemaleButton;
 private RadioButton genderMaleButton;
 private Button getObjectId,sndpush;
 private EditText ageEditText, frndidEditText, objectidEditText;
 private RadioGroup genderRadioGroup;
 private String FrndTextString, ageTextString, objectid;
 private ParseObject sid;

 public static final String GENDER_MALE = "male";
 public static final String GENDER_FEMALE = "female";
 protected static final String ParseIntallation = null;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 
 Parse.initialize(this, "c7fOlMSS4S8rxI53m0u49maP1Kab8PWVWSNwVu3s", "0xOUq1uoDb2NIi1jYZHWANZ9PP4X4W7vDfcA1UOw"); 
 PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
 ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    
  
   ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
   installation.saveInBackground();
    
  // Track app opens.
  ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

 
        getObjectId = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_button);
        genderFemaleButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.gender_female_button);
  genderMaleButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.gender_male_button);
  ageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age_edit_text);
  genderRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.gender_radio_group);
  frndidEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.frndid_edit_text);
  sndpush = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_push);
  sndpush.setEnabled(true);
  
  sndpush.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 
   public void onClick(View v) {
    JSONObject obj;
    try {
     obj =new JSONObject();
     obj.put("alert","erwerwe");
     obj.put("action","com.parse.pushnotifications.UPDATE_STATUS");
     obj.put("customdata","My string");
  
 
     ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
     ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
     query.whereEqualTo("objectId",objectidEditText.getText().toString() );
        push.setQuery(query);
     push.setData(obj);
     push.sendInBackground(); 
    }
    catch (JSONException e) 
    {
     
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
   }
  });

  // vk
  objectidEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.objectid_edit_text);
  getObjectId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    getObjectId();

   }
  });
 }

 @Override
 public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();

  // Display the current values for this user, such as their age and gender.
  displayUserProfile();
  refreshUserProfile();

 }

 // Save the user's profile to their installation.
 public void saveUserProfile(View view) {
  
  ageTextString = ageEditText.getText().toString();
  FrndTextString = frndidEditText.getText().toString();

  if (ageTextString.length() > 0) {
   sid.put("age",
     Integer.valueOf(ageTextString));
  }
  if (FrndTextString.length() > 0) {
   sid.put("FriendId",
     FrndTextString);
  }
  
  if (ageTextString.length() > 0) {
   ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().put("age", Integer.valueOf(ageTextString));
  }
  
  if (FrndTextString.length() > 0) {
   ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().put("FriendId", Integer.valueOf(FrndTextString));
   
  }

  if (genderRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == genderFemaleButton
    .getId()) {
   sid.put("gender",
     GENDER_FEMALE);
  } else if (genderRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == genderMaleButton
    .getId()) {
   sid.put("gender",
     GENDER_MALE);
  } else {
   sid.remove("gender");
  }

  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ageEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);

  sid.saveInBackground(
    new SaveCallback() {
     @Override
     public void done(ParseException e) {
      if (e == null) {
       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
         getApplicationContext(),
         R.string.alert_dialog_success,
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       toast.show();
      } else {
       e.printStackTrace();

       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
         getApplicationContext(),
         R.string.alert_dialog_failed,
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       toast.show();
      }
     }
    });
 }

 // Get the user's Id from parse.com.
 @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
 public void getObjectId() {

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("sid");
  query.whereEqualTo("FriendId", FrndTextString);
  query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback() {
   public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (object == null) {
     Log.d("objectId", "The getFirst request failed.");
    } else {
     String objectid = object.getObjectId();
     objectidEditText.setText(objectid);
     sndpush.setEnabled(true);
     Log.d("objectId", "Retrieved the object.");
    }
   }
  });


 }

 // Refresh the UI with the data obtained from the current ParseInstallation
 // object.
 private void displayUserProfile() {
  sid =ParseInstallation.create("sid");
  String gender = sid.getString(
    "gender");
  int age = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getInt("age");

  if (gender != null) {
   genderMaleButton.setChecked(gender.equalsIgnoreCase(GENDER_MALE));
   genderFemaleButton.setChecked(gender
     .equalsIgnoreCase(GENDER_FEMALE));
  } else {
   genderMaleButton.setChecked(false);
   genderFemaleButton.setChecked(false);
  }

  if (age > 0) {
   ageEditText.setText(Integer.valueOf(age).toString());
  }

 }

 private void refreshUserProfile() {
  ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().refreshInBackground(
    new RefreshCallback() {

     @Override
     public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
      if (e == null) {
       displayUserProfile();
      }
     }
    });
 }
}
```

Please help me in solving this issue as I googled a lot but haven’t found anything good solution.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you can't have custom classes even if it is under installation class for `ParsePush` you can only use Installation class query.

Comment: Ok  thanx but if I try to get the object id from installation class and try to send the push according to object id it also give error.....i use the following code

Comment: What's your new code

Comment: Hello Asdi, check this link...http://piratepad.net/ep/pad/view/ro.WwZ9v6FX1a6/latest

Comment: Please post it in your post or use the site pastebin!

Comment: Hello Aadi..i have post the complete code in my post please check...i really frustrated.

Comment: You are still sending using a custom class query. You can access only ParseInstallation query. i.e ParseInstallation.getQuery() nothing else.

Comment: I have updated my code...as you say please check is it correct or wrong....

Comment: It is wrong and I told you the reason why it's wrong

Comment: Thanx Aadi....for your response...